# Copy evertyhing inside a folder to current folder

Tags: unix

I have a folder called ccwp inside /var/www/html

The folder destinations are

```
/var/www/html/ccwp/<any and all files and folders>
```

How do I change it to

```
/var/www/html/<any and all files and folders>
```

Comment: Do you want to copy? Or to move?

Comment: why dont u just fire `cp /var/www/html/ccwp/*.* /var/www/html/*.*`

Comment: @AmneshGoel Because it only tries to copy files with a dot in the name, additionally ignoring any subdirectories. Apart from that the second `*.*` will make it behave weird at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy all the contents (and leave the originals in place)

```
cp -r /var/www/html/ccwp/* /var/www/html/
```

If you want to move the contents

```
mv /var/www/html/ccwp/* /var/www/html/
```

EDIT: To also get all hidden files in the copy, try rsync

```
rsync -rtv /var/www/html/ccwp/ /var/www/html/
```

Comment: I would use `-a` instead of `-r`. And if there are hidden files in `cwwp`, they won't be copied/moved.